# Setting multiple values in stream list using for each reference in Java 8

Tags: java, foreach, java-stream

Below is the code snippet, I want to set `isDeleted`, `modifiedDate` & `modifiedBy` in a single statement using Stream API.

How can I do it?

```
List<CtStaticIPDetailsList> ctStaticIPDetailsList =new ArrayList()<>;

ctStaticIPDetailsList.stream().forEach(l -> l.setIsDeleted(true));

ctStaticIPDetailsList.stream()
    .forEach(l -> l.setModifiedDate(new Date()));

ctStaticIPDetailsList.stream()
    .forEach(l -> l.setModifiedBy(boqCreationDTO.getUserId()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't get obsessed with streams, trying to apply them everywhere.

The operations you're performing doesn't require a generating a Stream. You can use [`Iterable.forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)) if you want to express it with a lambda.

```
List<CtStaticIPDetailsList> ctStaticIPDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();
    
ctStaticIPDetailsList.forEach(l -> {
    l.setIsDeleted(true);
    l.setModifiedDate(new Date());
    l.setModifiedBy(boqCreationDTO.getUserId());
});
```

Also avoid using `java.util.Date`, this class is obsolete. Sinse Java 8 we have new Time API represented by classes like `Instant`, `LocalDateTime`, etc. which reside in the [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package.